# iPhone SDK - Shedule action even if iPhone is rebooted?

Tags: iphone, timer, synchronization, delay, ios6

I'm currently creating an app for both Android and iOS, and I'm currently working on the iPhone version. What I want is to give the user 5 options which are all different sync-intervals: 30 minutes, 3 hours, 12 hours, 24 hours and "every monday, 6'o clock". I've used the Account manager and sync functions in Android for the Android version, but I don't know if there's anything equivalent to this in the iPhone SDK. The only thing I've found so far, was to use a NSTimer. I now would really like to know if the NSTimer is being destroyed when the iPhone is rebooted, and if it is - is there another way to do this?

I'm using the iOS SDK 6.0 and the minimum target is iOS 6.0.

Comment: interesting thought, can't be done with NSTimer as it doesn't run in the background.....

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do it then?  I really don't know how I can do this now... :/

Comment: there is a little information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830164/start-a-location-aware-background-service-in-ios-on-boot but it doesn't look promising

Comment: Thank you. Really hoped that there was something like "addPeriodicSync", but I guess I have to try to make it work in an other way then.